# Use no global Mapper variable of Automapper in AfterMap

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there a way to get the current mapping context in AutoMapper when using AfterMap?

```
public class DefaultMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<SomeList, List<SpecialItem>>()
            .AfterMap((src, dst) => dst.AddRange(
                 src.elem.Select(Mapper.Map<SpecialItem>)));
```

I tried to use `.ConstructUsing(context => {})` but this gave me not the same results as when using AfterMap (!?). But I don't want to access the global variable `Mapper` here. Is there a way to get around accessing the global variable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could as an alternative use `ConvertUsing<TSource, TDestination>` such as:

`CreateMap<data.BillCycle, domain.BillCycle>().ConvertUsing<BillCycleConverter>();`

The class will implement `ITypeConverter<TSource, TDestination>` and gives you access to the mapper:

```
public class BillCycleConverter : ITypeConverter<data.BillCycle, domain.BillCycle>
{
    public domain.BillCycle Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        context.Engine.Map<X, Y>...
    }
}
```

[Custom Type Converters](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters)