# Automapper - ignore item in collection based on predicate

Tags: c#, automapper

I have deep nested collections that all implement an interface:

```
public ICmsAware
{
    DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

So the concrete classes would look something like:

```
public class Parent : ICmsAware
{
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class Child : ICmsAware
{
    public List<GrandChild> GrandChildren { get; set; }

    public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild : ICmsAware
{
    public DateTime? InactiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

What I'd like to do with automapper is use an extension method on each mapping to ignore any ICmsAware entities where `InactiveDate.HasValue == true`

e.g.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentViewModel>().IgnoreInactiveItem();
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, ChildViewModel>().IgnoreInactiveItem();
Mapper.CreateMap<GrandChild, GrandChildViewModel>().IgnoreInactiveItem();
```

The only examples of anything remotely similar to this scenario that I have found have ignored properties on the entities, rather than the entire entity itself.

Comment: Have a go at using custom type converters. I added an example here a little while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267497/use-no-global-mapper-variable-of-automapper-in-aftermap/32269414#32269414

Comment: Would that be able to remove items from a collection, or just replace items that don't meet my criteria with null?

Comment: So from what I gather, in the method you override (`Convert()`), you can loop through all the entities in the source collection, perform your tests then map the ones you want adding to your collection and then add them.

Comment: ah ok, so that would only work if i'm mapping a collection, rather than the items within the collection wouldn't it?

Comment: You can map the items within the collection too, but maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: ok i'll try that and post back here if it doesn't work. thanks for your help!

Comment: Take it there was no problems with this? 

Comment: I gave up in the end and just mapped it manually (I was already halfway through doing this anyway).  Will revisit it though as the code is awful :)